# Poor Performance Writing to Firebase Realtime Database from Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have been developing a game where on the user submitting data, the client writes some data to a Firebase Realtime Database. I then have a Google Cloud Function which is triggered onUpdate. That function checks the submissions from various players in a particular game and if certain criteria are met, the function writes an update to the DB which causes the clients to move to the next round of the game.

This is all working, however, I have found performance to be quite poor.

I've added logging to the function and can see that the function takes anywhere from 2-10ms to complete, which is acceptable. The issue is that the update is often written anywhere from 10-30 SECONDS after the function has returned the update.

To determine this, my function obtains the UTC epoch timestamp from just before writing the update, and stores this as a key with the value being the Firebase server timestamp.

I then have manually checked the two timestamps to arrive at the time between return and database write:

The strange thing is that I have another cloud function which is triggered by an HTTP request, and found that the update from that function is typically from 0.5-2 seconds after the function calls the DB update() API.

The difference between these two functions, aside from how they are triggered, is how the data is written back to the DB.

The onUpdate() function writes data by returning:

```
return after.ref.update(updateToWrite);
```

Whereas the HTTP request function writes data by calling the update API:

```
dbRef.update({
        // object to write
    });
```

I've provided a slightly stripped out version of my onUpdate function here (same structure but sanitised function names) :

```
exports.onGameUpdate = functions.database.ref("/games/{gameId}")
    .onUpdate(async(snapshot, context) => {

        console.time("onGameUpdate");

        let id = context.params.gameId;
        let after = snapshot.after;
        let updatedSnapshot = snapshot.after.val();

        if (updatedSnapshot.serverShouldProcess && !isFinished) {

            processUpdate().then((res)=>{

                // some logic to check res, and if criteria met, move on to promises to determine update data
    
                determineDataToWrite().then((updateToWrite)=>{
                    
                    // get current time
                    var d = new Date();
                    let triggerTime = d.getTime();

                    // I use triggerTime as the key, and firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP as the value
                    if(updateToWrite["timestamps"] !== null && updateToWrite["timestamps"] !== undefined){
                        let timestampsCopy = updateToWrite["timestamps"];

                        timestampsCopy[triggerTime] = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
                        
                        updateToWrite["timestamps"][triggerTime] = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
                    }else{
                        let timestampsObj = {};
                        timestampsObj[triggerTime] = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

                        updateToWrite["timestamps"] = timestampsObj;
                    }

                    // write the update to the database
                    return after.ref.update(updateToWrite);

                }).catch((error)=>{
                    // error handling
                })
                }

                // this is just here because ES Linter complains if there's no return
                return null;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // error handling
            })
        }
    });
```

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks :)

Comment: Please include the logging output that leads you to your performance claims in the question too.

Comment: At first glance, your promises aren't chained correctly resulting in your function returning before the logic has finished. While your function MAY work as it is now, it will never be guaranteed to work as the function may be shut down prior to completing the task. If you fix up the chaining you should see that your function takes longer than 10ms.

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman. I was planning to rework the promise chaining but didn't realise it was tied to my database update performance. Reworked it and found that my performance issue is resolved! It's worth noting that my function still executes in less than 10ms in most cases, apart from the occasional instance where it needs to perform some additional logic in which case it takes about 50ms.